# Rails3 autocomplete: Passing additional values (from another text field)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I'm using Autocomplete plugin for rails 3 (rails3-jquery-autocomplete) and I need to pass into the controller a value from another text field.  The reason is that previous field has a value that the SQL needs to filter also on.
I know there is a parameter called id_element which might allow me to pass another field but I'm not sure if that is the correct way of doing this.

So, I need both the substring from the current field (which is working) and string from another text box in the view which both will be used in the query for the suggestion box.

Regards,
Johann

Answer (score 0):

I only have experience with jquery-autocomplete, not the rails version. In that one, there's a search event you can attach to: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-search - there you can do an $.ajax call, sending whatever information you want from the page with it, and then set the "source" option of the autocomplete to the returned result.

Comment: Did it work like you wanted? I have that setup working on one of my own sites.

Comment: Hello Emil.  No I haven't been able to make it work.  It would be helpful if you could give me some pointers.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can solve it by reading : [Autocomplete in rails with jquery](http://blog.inspired.no/autocomplete-with-jquery-in-rails-270)

Comment: Completely unrelated to the problem